# How do I check if a subreddit exists in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, reddit

So I was making a command to browse reddit for images, using the npm package 'trev'

```js
const trev = require("trev");
module.exports = {
    name: 'reddit',
    description: "Gets an image from reddit",
    async execute(message, args, client, Discord) {
        
        const sub = args[0]
        const subr = await trev.getCustomSubreddit(sub)
```

it works perfectly fine if I enter a subreddit which exists, but if i enter an inexistent subreddit for the first argument, then the code crashes and gives me and error, so I want to know if there is a way to check if the subreddit actually exists.

Comment: Try adding `if (!subr) return;`

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to use a other package.
trev is broken for getting a inexistent subreddit
The `index.js` has a var typo :

```
async getCustomSubreddit(subreddit) {
...
      while (r[0] === undefined && tentatives < 5) {
            let r = await getsubreddit(subreddit);
            tentatives++;
      }
...
}
```

It should be :

```
async getCustomSubreddit(subreddit) {
...
      while (r[0] === undefined && tentatives < 5) {
            let r = await this.getSubreddit(subreddit);
            tentatives++;
      }
...
}
```

You could try and modify the package to make this work, in the `\node_modules\trev\index.js` file

By doing that, the function would actually work, and requesting a inexistent subreddit would return `undefined` and log out :

```
[-] Broken subreddit: /r/subreddityouwant
```